# Regex not supported in sql command with "contains" clause

Tags: mysql, regex, windows

I am not a seasonal Windows user, I got a task wherein I had to query the Window Index search table i.e "**Systemindex**" for fetching some user specific data from the db.

And for this I have to match a pattern basically a regular expression while fetching the data.

```
SELECT System.FileName, System.ItemPathDisplay, System.DateCreated, System.DateModified, System.ItemName, System.KindText FROM Systemindex WHERE Contains('“(?=^[A-Za-z\d!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\+=]{9,32}$)”');
```

The above would allow us to search for say stored passwords.

But when I query the db using the below command I was getting an error. And later I came to know that the "contains" clause 
does not support regular expression. Is there an alternative to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is REGEXP operator http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html,
use smth like this

```
SELECT * FROM Systemindex WHERE some_column REGEXP 'your_regex'
```